# Jquery works for one button, but not for the other identical one?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, button, jbutton

I am making a php forum and am using identical buttons such that if one is clicked, it does a function. Anyway, for this question, I have an altered form of my php script with the same problem. This script is supposed to alert a message if a button is clicked. Both buttons have same names, but alerting only works for the first button not the second one. Why? How should I solve it?

buttons.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function() {
$('#oneButton').bind('click', alertButtonClick);
});

function alertButtonClick() 
{
    alert("There was a button clicked");                                                                      
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php

    echo "<div class='comments'>";
    echo "<form id='theForm'>";
    echo "<button type='button' id='oneButton'>Post Comment</button></form></div>";

    echo "<div class='comments'>";
    echo "<form id='theForm'>";
    echo "<button type='button' id='oneButton'>Post Comment</button></form></div>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
When I fixed the button issue, I quickly faced another problem. I have been trying to solve it for a long time now. Anyway, I have posted two codes below. Each div features value, text area, and button. When I write text in the first div and click the 'post comment' button, it isplays that text and the value=1, which is what I want for both buttons. However if I do the same for the second button, it still outputs stuff for the first button, not for the second one, Why? Here are the codes, try them out and help me out.

button2.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript"         src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("document").ready(function() 
{
    $('.oneButton').bind('click',sendInfoToServer);
});

function sendInfoToServer() 
{
    $('span.commentSent').load('button3.php',
    $('#theForm').serializeArray());
}

</script>
</head>
<body>

    <span class='commentSent'></span>

<?php

    echo "<div class='comments'>";
    echo "<form id='theForm'>";
    echo "<input type=hidden name='mess_block' value=1>";
    echo "<textarea name='comment' class='comment' cols=60 rows=2>Enter Comment…</textarea><br />"; 
    echo "<button type='button' class='oneButton'>Post Comment</button></form></div>"; //check the change

    echo "<div class='comments'>";
    echo "<form id='theForm'>";
    echo "<input type=hidden name='mess_block' value=2>";
    echo "<textarea name='comment' class='comment' cols=60 rows=2>Enter Comment…</textarea><br />"; 
    echo "<button type='button' class='oneButton'>Post Comment</button></form></div>"; // check the change
?>

</body>
</html>
```

button3.php

```
<?php

    $mb = $_POST["mess_block"];
    echo $mb . "<br/>";

    $mt = $_POST["comment"];
    echo $mt . "<br/>";

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace `$('#oneButton').bind('click', alertButtonClick);` to `$('button').bind('click', alertButtonClick);`

Comment: In short: You have two forms with the same id. And you need to create handlers for each form. I'd recommend you ask a new question.

Comment: I don't know to solve it, I am trying to create sort of a forum where people an click on random posts and reply to them. Like what reply sites like yahoo or reddit do. I don't think they create handlers for each because the posts could be in the thousands. I don't wanna create a new question, I may be rated down because I have asked this question

Comment: when you do $ ('# theForm').serializeArray() are serialized all forms with id 'theForm' on the page. you need to specify unique id or name for each form.

Comment: I have a computer program creating and naming all forms, so they are all alike, I expect hundreds of forms. But I want each one's independent information if its button is clicked

Comment: That is so great, that will work for me. I notice you have id=form-1 and id=form-2, Since my initial program was putting id = theform automatically for every new form created, is there an automated way of doing your style?

Comment: In this example I did not use the id (get form from event.target.form). but You can use id as key in foreach loop http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH for coming back and helping me out, I figured Ii could increment the id as a value

Answer (score 2):

You cannot share IDs on HTML elements. Try changing the ID on one button or using classes instead:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('.clickable-button').on('click', function() {
        alert('There was a button clicked');
    }
});
</script>
// ....
<button class="clickable-button">Button</button>
<button class="clickable-button">Button</button>
<button class="clickable-button">Button</button>
```

Comment: so what do forums like reddit do, do they have to make different buttons for every post, I think they share them.

Comment: The buttons will all have a class on them, that will share a common function, but the function will analyse what button was clicked and perform a function based on that.

Comment: @MattDathew As noted, they will probably share a `class` name, then perhaps use `$(this)` to get the value of the specific element clicked.

Comment: For example if you want to hide the element just before the button you can use `$(this).prev().hide();`